# Value does not live long enough with a generic function that creates a container, adds items to it, then iterates over the items

Tags: generics, iterator, rust, traits, lifetime

I'm trying to write a generic function that creates a default value and iterates through its internal "buffer." All this happens within the function with no arguments nor return values. I seem to have the lifetimes declared incorrectly and I am having a hard time setting them correctly for this to work.

Here is an example type that implements the `Default` and `IntoIterator` traits, as well as a new trait called `Foo` that requires one method.

```
trait Foo<T> {
    fn add(&mut self, T);
}

struct FooBar<T> {
    buf: Vec<Option<T>>,
    len: usize,
}

impl<T> FooBar<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let buf = Vec::new();
        let len = 0;
        Self { buf, len }
    }

    fn iter(&self) -> FooBarIter<T> {
        FooBarIter { foo: self, pos: 0 }
    }
}

impl<T> Foo<T> for FooBar<T> {
    fn add(&mut self, val: T) {
        self.buf.push(Some(val));
        self.len += 1;
    }
}

impl<T> Default for FooBar<T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new()
    }
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> IntoIterator for &'a FooBar<T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    type IntoIter = FooBarIter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.iter()
    }
}
```

`FooBar` just adds values to a vector which it owns. To only allow a non-consuming iteration, I defined an iterator which borrows the underlying `Vec` and maintains the "current" index during the iteration, returning a reference to each element which the consumer borrows.

```
struct FooBarIter<'a, T: 'a> {
    foo: &'a FooBar<T>,
    pos: usize,
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for FooBarIter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.foo.len <= self.pos {
            return None;
        }

        self.pos += 1;
        self.foo.buf[self.pos - 1].as_ref()
    }
}
```

A generic function creates a default value, adds some items (of type `&str`), then iterates though them by reference. I seem to have declared the lifetimes incorrectly because Rust complains that the borrowed value of `FooBar` doesn't live long enough. However, it says that it lives until the end of the function, so I'm confused as to how long Rust is expecting the borrow to actually live.

```
fn start<'a, T: 'a>()
where
    T: Foo<&'a str> + Default,
    &'a T: IntoIterator<Item = &'a &'a str>,
{
    let mut f = T::default();
    f.add("abcd");
    f.add("efgh");

    for val in &f {
        println!("{}", *val);
    }

    f.add("ijkl");

    for val in &f {
        println!("{}", *val);
    }
}

fn main() {
    start::<FooBar<&str>>();
}
```

Here is the error which states that that `&f` does not live long enough because the "borrowed value only lives until" the end of the function.

```
error[E0597]: `f` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:70:17
   |
70 |     for val in &f {
   |                 ^ does not live long enough
...
73 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 61:1...
  --> src/main.rs:61:1
   |
61 | / fn start<'a, T: 'a>()
62 | | where
63 | |     T: Foo<&'a str> + Default,
64 | |     &'a T: IntoIterator<Item = &'a &'a str>,
...  |
72 | |     }
73 | | }
   | |_^
```

I've also tried setting a different lifetime parameter for the `&'a IntoIterator` trait, but then I end up going around in circles for other errors, not really getting close to setting the correct lifetimes.

To further illustrate what I'm trying to achieve with `FooBar`, here is an example of what I'm trying to do if `FooBar` was instead a `Vec`.

```
fn start() {
    let mut f = Vec::new();
    f.push("abcd");
    f.push("efgh");

    for val in &f {
        println!("{}", *val);
    }

    f.push("ijkl");

    for val in &f {
        println!("{}", *val);
    }
}
```

Am I even on the right track with trying to figure out the lifetime parameters, or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what you are attempting is currently impossible.

To start with, your error message is because **the caller** is specifying the lifetime when passed to `start`:

```
fn start<'a, T: 'a>()
```

This doesn't make any sense because the caller *cannot* control the lifetime. For example, what if the call was `start::<Vec<&'static str>>` but the function created some temporary values? This lifetime is also tied to the iterator implementation — if the reference to the value lives as long as the caller dictates, then it can be iterated.

In many similar cases, *higher-ranked trait bounds* are the solution, however, the closest I can get is a bit different:

```
trait Foo<T> {
    fn add(&mut self, T);
}

impl<T> Foo<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn add(&mut self, val: T) {
        self.push(val);
    }
}

fn start<T>()
where
    T: Default + Foo<&'static str>,
    for<'a> &'a T: IntoIterator,
    for<'a, 'b> &'a <&'b T as IntoIterator>::Item: std::fmt::Display,
{
    let mut f = T::default();
    f.add("abcd");
    f.add("efgh");

    for val in &f {
        println!("{}", &val);
    }

    f.add("ijkl");

    for val in &f {
        println!("{}", &val);
    }
}

fn main() {
    start::<Vec<&str>>();
}
```

The main sticking point is `T: Default + Foo<&'static str>`. As far as what I can see, there's no way to pass in a concrete type for `T` that could use a HRTB defined by the function. In this case, we can use `'static`. If we tried to use `for <'a> T: Default + Foo<&'a str>`, we get the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'a> std::vec::Vec<&str>: Foo<&'a str>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:33:5
   |
33 |     start::<Vec<&str>>();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `for<'a> Foo<&'a str>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<&str>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <std::vec::Vec<T> as Foo<T>>
   = note: required by `start`
```

The compiler doesn't know to match up the lifetime declared at the call site with the one specified by the HRTB. I believe, but am not sure, that [*generic associated types*](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md) might address the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Shepmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155423/shepmaster) for pointing me in the right direction with HRTBs. After reading up on the topic, I was able to have the function itself provide the lifetime of `FooBarIter` and `FooBarIter::Item` instead. `FooBarIter` can now be borrowed and last until the end of the function. The lifetime of `FooBar` can still be provided by the caller.

Here is the only change that was necessary for me to make this finally compile.

```
fn start<'a, T>()
where
    T: Foo<&'a str> + Default,
    for<'b> &'b T: IntoIterator<Item = &'b &'a str>,
{
    let mut f = T::default();
    f.add("abcd");
    f.add("efgh");

    for val in &f {
        println!("{}", *val);
    }

    f.add("ijkl");

    for val in &f {
        println!("{}", *val);
    }
}
```